# Two label and their action on tap on Android Custom keyboard

Tags: android

how to display 2 different label one big other small like in the picture and how to implement there action of long pressing call the small label in custom Android keyboard

Android Custom keyboard style which i want

[image: Android Custom keyboard style which i want]

Comment: This may help you, http://www.infiniterecursion.us/2011/02/android-activity-custom-keyboard.html

Comment: but your code not work as i want to type 1 by long pressing on q